# Struggling to transmit data to a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am really new to VueJS, and I'm trying to build some kind of system where I have four pages available with Vue-Router. These pages are "ranked" from 1 to 4, and if the new page has a higher rank than the old one, the transition is set to "transition-left", else, "transition-right".

My problem here is that I can't manage to pass the result of the comparison to the child component. Here is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Landing from "./components/Landing.vue";
import Bio from "./components/Bio.vue";
import Shop from "./components/Shop.vue";
import Contact from "./components/Contact.vue";
import App from "./components/App.vue";
import "./assets/style.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter);
let transitionName = "";

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",

  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: Landing,
      meta: { order: 1 }
    },
    {
      path: "/biography",
      component: Bio,
      meta: { order: 2 }
    },
    {
      path: "/shop",
      component: Shop,
      meta: { order: 3 }
    },

    {
      path: "/contact",
      component: Contact,
      meta: { order: 4 }
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.order > from.meta.order) {
    transitionName = "slide-left";
  } else {
    transitionName = "slide-right";
  }
  next();
});

let vm = new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    transitionName: transitionName
  },
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

And here is how I tried to pass the "transitionName" value to "App.vue":

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition :name="name">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["transitionname"],
  data: function() {
    return { name: this.transitionname };
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm thinking that maybe I did the `new Vue` part wrong, and that's not how you pass datas to a child component, but I can't find a working way to pass it correctly.

As a result, everything works, but there aren't any transition, so I guess the `:name="name"` equals nothing.

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I expect what you really want to do here is watch `$route` in App, and change `name` as it changes.

Comment: possibly just a typo in this question - but you have `transitionName` in the Vue app instantiation but `transitionname` (all lowercase) in your component

Comment: @hackerrdave Ow, you're right, and I made this mistake in my code too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I might approach what you want to achieve. Basically all you want to do is watch the `$route` in your `App` component.

```
watch:{
  $route(to, from){
    if (to.meta.order > from.meta.order) {
      this.name = "slide-left";
    } else {
      this.name = "slide-right";
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XBpGEE?editors=1010) of that working (without the actual transitions).

Comment: Thank you! It took me some time to understand but it was easier than I thought!